# "onWindowFocusChanged()" not excuted when switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity, with multiple master-detail fragments in the activity.
Fragment 1 is opened with a button click in Activity, and Fragment 2 is open with a button click in Fragment 1.

**Activity => Fragment 1 => Fragment 2**

As I know, onWindowFocusChanged() is called when Activity switch to Fragment 1.
However, it is not called when Fragment 1 switch to Fragment 2.

Is there any callback method invoked when switching Fragment 1 to Fragment 2 that I can use?

I need this call back so that I can render my Fragment 2 layout correctly as I added some TableRow with TextView programmatically in Fragment 2.

I tried using onCreateView(), onStart(), onCreate() methods in Fragment 2 but it doesn't work because the layout(TextView, TableRow) that I added programmatically in Fragment 2 isn't added to the RootView yet.

Any suggestion or solution?

Comment: Are you adding Fragment 2 over Fragment 1 or replacing them when switching between fragments? When replacing, onCreateView() will be called in Fragment 2

Comment: I am adding Fragment 2 over Fragment 1, means Fragment 1 is not closed.